# showing error on htaccess address rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i am want to convert url:

`/tld/?=com` to `/tld/com/`

my full htaccess code is as below:

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(whois|error)(?:\.php)?[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(php?|jpg|gif|png|css|js|html|json|xml|eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|zip|csv|xlsx|webp|txt|gz|rar)$ [NC]
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

##### Rewite #####

##RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\$ /tld.php?tld=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\$ /tld.php?tld=$1 [L]
```

but its show 500 error so please help

Comment: On browser you want to redirect `/tld/?=com to /tld/com/`, but from backend how you want to serve it? Could you please make it clear once, thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 when i open on browser: /tld/com/ than it should work. redirect is not  required, Thanks

Comment: So you want to hit url like `http://localhost:80/tid/com/`? If you could mention from which url in browser TO which url in backend you want to serve that will make things more clear. I am sorry its not clear yet, thank you.

Comment: real url: https://www.domaindumper.com/tld/?tld=com to https://www.domaindumper.com/tld/com/

Comment: Yes i will open direct on browser as : https://www.domaindumper.com/tld/com/

Comment: Sure, so you mean we will hit url like `http://localhost:80/tld/?tld=com` and it should be redirected on browser to `http://localhost:80/tld/com`. But again my question is link `http://localhost:80/tld/com` will be served by which file in backend? Why I am asking is if its not clear then you may get 404 error, let me know, thank you.

Comment: localhost:80/tld/?tld=com is already working and want make workable too: localhost:80/tld/com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it this way:

```sh
Options -Indexes -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(whois|error)(?:\.php)?[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(php?|jpg|gif|png|css|js|html|json|xml|eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|zip|csv|xlsx|webp|txt|gz|rar)$ [NC]
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301,NE]

# ignore all rules below this for files and directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} .
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^tld/([\w-]+)/?$ tld.php?tld=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but its showing 500 error, can pls check again

Comment: I had already tested before posting. Which URL is causing 500 and what does Apache error.log show for that error?

Comment: its showing this error: AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

Comment: after enabling log level now error show as: [builtwith.domaindumper.com/sid#561cb869e648][rid#7f65b404cfa0/initial/redir#10] [perdir /httpdocs/] trying to replace prefix /httpdocs/ with /
[Wed Jan 20 11:56:09.463243 2021] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 26252:tid 140075182581504] mod_rewrite.c(470): [client 110.235.228.141:40018] 163.172.91.159 - - [builtwith.domaindumper.com/sid#561cb869e648][rid#7f65b404cfa0/initial/redir#10] [perdir /httpdocs/] internal redirect with /tld/com.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]

Comment: please note live url: https://builtwith.domaindumper.com/tld.php

Comment: now showing 404 after code update . my current new url is: https://builtwith.domaindumper.com/tld/com/ i have tested on terminal also.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227571/discussion-between-anubhava-and-shiv-singh).